# How to pass boolean in Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, plugins, boolean

My JS call looks like this

```
cordova.exec(function () { }, function () { }, "ProgressHUD", "show", [ _message, _messageLong, determined ]);
```

where determined is a true or false value

In the function I'm doing this

```
BOOL determined = [command argumentAtIndex:2];

if(determined) {
    // do thing
} else {
    // do other thing
}
```

No idea why this doesn't work. If I try `NSNumber*` or `NSString*` instead of BOOL then my log gives me 1 or 0 as my passed in value.

But I can't even for some reason do

```
if(determined == 1) {
```

If I do this, the code doesn't even run, or throw a syntax error for that matter.

Any ideas how to check for a boolean value in Objective C here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to check for a boolean as such

```
if([determined boolValue] == YES) {
```

Answer (score 1):

this is currently working for me

```
//JS interface
cordova.exec(function () { }, function () { }, "Class", "Method", [true]);

//Objective-C Method
NSNumber boolParam = [urlCommand.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
if([boolParam  isEqual: @(YES)]){
    ...do stuff
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `NSNumber*`?

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
BOOL myBool = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:1] boolValue];
```